# autocomplete con archivo externo json

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete

tengo este código y funciona, solo que deseo hacer que la fuente de las ciudades las obtenga desde un archivo Json externo, por que deseo colocar muchas ciudades. Pero no logro crearlo.

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Xalapa, Ver. Mx",
      "Boca del Rio, Ver. Mx",
      "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes, México",
      "La Mascota, Aguascalientes, México",
      "Matamoros [Congregación], Aguascalientes, México"
    ];
    $( "#ciudades" ).autocomplete({
      source: (request, response) => {
        // Filtramos el arreglo de tags
        let result = availableTags.filter(tag => {
          // Implementamos nuestro filtro personalizado
          return tag.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase());
        });
        // Llamamos a `response` con los datos filtrados
        response(result);
      },
      change: function(e, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
          $(this).val("");
        }
      },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 0) 
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
        })
          .on("keydown", function(e) 
          {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) 
            {
              $(this).val("");
            }
          })
  } );
```

sé que en el source debe llevar el nombre del archivo JSON, pero este codigo me lo pasó una persona aquí en este foro y permite listar las ciudades por inicial ademas de que valida y no permite seleccionar una ciudad que no exista en la lista.

Comment: Eso no es un JSON es un array de strings

Comment: precisamente es la pregunta, ese es un array de cadenas, unos tags, lo que deseo es obtener esas ciudades desde un archivo JSON externo

Comment: ¿El contenido del archivo `JSON` va a cambiar dependiendo de lo que ingrese el usuario o siempre va a tener el mismo contenido?

Comment: el archivo JSON contendrá siempre las mismas ciudades marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la solucion que consegui a tu problema. Se Carga un un archivo JSON desde un Ajax en forma sincrona y en el  metodo success: se pasan los datos a la variable **availableTags,** luego se coloca el bloque de la funcion que esta usando el autocomplete.

Este es el nuevo codigo que carga la lista desde un archivo externo JSON.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba de lectura de datos en formato JSON</title>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var availableTags  = [];

              $.ajax({ 
                    url: "datos.json", 
                    type: "GET",  
                    async: false, 
                    success: function(json){ 
                        //Proceso de los datos recibidos
                        availableTags = json['ciudad'];  
                        $( function() {

    $( "#ciudades" ).autocomplete({
      source: (request, response) => {
        // Filtramos el arreglo de tags
        let result = availableTags.filter(tag => {
          // Implementamos nuestro filtro personalizado
          return tag.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase());
        });
        // Llamamos a `response` con los datos filtrados
        response(result);
      },
      change: function(e, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
          $(this).val("");
        }
      },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 0) 
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
        })
          .on("keydown", function(e) 
          {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) 
            {
              $(this).val("");
            }
          })
  } );
                    }
              });

         }); // fin document.ready
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="">

      <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="ciudades">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Aqui abajo esta el archivo de carga llamado datos.json

```
{

    "ciudad": [ "Xalapa, Ver. Mx",
        "Boca del Rio, Ver. Mx",
        "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes, México",
        "La Mascota, Aguascalientes, México",
        "Matamoros [Congregación], Aguascalientes, México",
        "Caracas, Venezuela",
        "Nueva York, Estados Unidos",
        "Los Ángeles, Estados Unidos"
    ]
}
```

Este es el resultado al ejecutar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy probando y no funciona, en el input al tener el foco, solo aparece una "A", mmm revisaré

Comment: ups me faltaban algunas librerias, genial

Comment: Alexander Rodriguez y para validarlo, es decir que forzosamente eligar una opciòn de la listada, por que actualmente, si teclean "L" como tienes en la imagen y pulsar Registrar, se queda con L, o debo hacer una pregunta nueva?

Comment: Se me ocurre dos cosas: 1) Al salir del foco del campo ciudad haga una consulta a la tabla mediante un AJAX y verifique que el usuario selecciono una ciudad de la lista. En caso contrario marca el campo y coloca el foco en este y no deja pasar al siguiente paso. 2)  grabar en un arreglo las ciudades sugeridas y al salir del foco comparar el valor del camppo con la lista del arreglo. Porque como esta ahora solo sugiere el contenido mas no valida.